# Is there a way to modify the HTTP_REFERRER before redirecting in Django?

Tags: python, django, redirect, http-status-code-301

Let's say someone is on www.yahoo.com, and then hits my URL www.mysite.com. Now, in Django, I want to do:

`return HttpResponseRedirect('https://www.google.com')`

However, when Google receives this request, they will see the HTTP_REFERER was Yahoo, but I want to modify the referer so it shows ‘www.mysite.com’. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do something like:

```
resp = HttpResponseRedirect('https://www.google.com')
resp['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'www.mysite.com'
return resp
```

This is because `HttpResponseRedirect` is a subclass of `HttpResponse`, so you can just set header fields [like you would for `HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields)

Comment: Not work for me: Nginx1.14.0+Gunicorn20.0.4+Django2.2